# Implementing Socket.IO in IOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

I am trying to implement Socket.IO in my iOS application. But am stuck at 2 places and can't get a way to solve it.

1. In my connection, I need to add headers. Can't get how to add headers in my obj-C code.

The code that I have implemented so far is as follows :

```
    // Init SocketIO
    // Need to ADD Header X_APP_ID along connecting ?
    _socketConnection = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [_socketConnection connectToHost:@"api.mintchal.com" onPort:80 ]; //  withParams:nil withNamespace:nil
```

Can anyone please help me with this point mentioned above. Searched a lot on net, but couldn't find so with iOS code. Had found headers added in web client in JS file, but can't get how to add here. Am stuck from 2-3 days on this point and don't get a way to sort out.

Was wondering 1 more thing, my 2-3 ViewControllers will be active in this socket connection. Right now, I have implemented socket.io in 1 viewController. Was thinking, how to code in such a way that this connection remains alive for all view controllers & need not implement the same in all views. Any ideas for the same are also highly appreciative.

Any help is highly appreciative. Thanks

Comment: @ipmcc, I am using this library only - https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc  . MY query is how to add headers while connecting to the server.

Comment: Heh, sorry about that. Guess I should read the whole question before commenting. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code using the latest socket.io-objc from https://github.com/gnap/socket.IO-objc/commit/02be0e114e4a33ff0a6adb26016f9d5cadab4f17 . I was already using it, but it wasn't the latest.   It has added feature to add headers.

Thanks